# How to add class or pseudoclass programmatically to custom control in JavaFX?

Tags: java, css, javafx, pseudo-class

In JavaScript world it is often set element class to denote it's appearance, which is later defined by CSS.

Is this so in JavaFX?

For example, what if I want to color negative value in red in [`TableView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/TableView.html) cells? I would not [code color directly](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html), but assigned some class to a cell, like "negative" and later would color it into red with `CSS`.

I found [`PseudoClass`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/css/PseudoClass.html) class. Is it intended for this? It is marked "since 8", so is there any more mature API for this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to add a style to a `Node` that you can toggle on and off, a `PseudoClass` is indeed the correct way to do it. It was indeed added in JavaFX 8.0, but that is the current stable version, so it is a mature API. Note that this creates a pseudoclass (`:classname` in CSS), not a "normal" class (`.classname` in CSS).

If you have a Node you want to style (lets call it `node`), you can use PseudoClass like this:

```
node.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("negative"), true);
```

Do the same thing, except with `false` as the second argument, to turn it off again.

Comment: Probably the `PseudoClass` should be stored in a `static final` field for efficiency, but good answer nonetheless...

Comment: The key is : not a "normal" class (.classname in CSS)